# How to efficiently fill adjacent columns of a data frame with values when filtering by row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with several portfolios and perfomance by day

```
  Date      P1             P2          P3           P4          P5
03.11.2022  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
07.11.2022  1,8           2,0          3,1         2,2         2,6
08.11.2022  0,4          -0,3         -0,5        -0,3        -0,3
09.11.2022  -1,7         -1,2          -1,4        -1,9        -2,0
10.11.2022  1,6           0,7           2,1         2,3        2,1
11.11.2022  0,2           0,2          -0,1         0,4         0,1
14.11.2022  0,3           0,1           0,5         0,8         1,0
15.11.2022  -1,4          -1,5          -2,2        -2,8        -2,8
16.11.2022  1,4            1,1          1,4         2,4         1,9
17.11.2022  -0,6           -0,1         -0,8        -0,2        0,3
```

It is desirable to obtain a dataframe filtered by specific rows

```
  Date      P1             P2          P3           P4          P5
03.11.2022  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
07.11.2022  1,8           1,8          1,8         1,8         1,8
08.11.2022  0,4          0,4           0,4         0,4         0,4
09.11.2022  -1,7         -1,7          -1,7        -1,7        -1,7
10.11.2022  1,6           0,7           0,7         0,7        0,7
11.11.2022  0,2           0,2           0,2         0,2         0,2 
14.11.2022  0,3           0,1           0,1         0,1         0,1
15.11.2022  -1,4          -1,5          -2,2        -2,2        -2,2
16.11.2022  1,4            1,1          1,4         1,4          1,4
17.11.2022  -0,6           -0,1         -0,8        -0,2        -0,2
```

Up to a certain number, I need to fill the data from the adjacent column, but then do this operation with other columns. I couldn't think of a better solution than

```
All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG[0:148] = All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG.iloc[0:148,[0]]
    All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P3'][149:168] = All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P2'][149:168]
    All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P4'][149:168] = All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P2'][149:168]
    All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P5'][149:168] = All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P2'][149:168]
    All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P4'][169:221] = All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P3'][169:221]
    All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P5'][169:221] = All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P3'][169:221]
    All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P5'][222:258] = All_portfolios_by_risk_rate_DataFrame_SG['P4'][222:258]
```

Tell me, is there a way to accomplish this task more elegantly?

Comment: Use `.loc[149:168, 'P3']` instead of `['P3'][149:168]` to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`

Comment: Your logic is not clear enough to know if this could be improved. Also, your example is not a [mre] (running our code would not do much since you need many more rows in the code).